# how to get full path from fileupload using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, path

I need to know how to get full path from fileupload using javascript,

I tried using the following coding but of no use

```
<input type="file" id="picField" onchange="preview(this)">

<script type="text/javascript">

function preview(test){
    var source=test.value;
    alert(source);
}
</script>
```

but in the alert message, i am getting only

```
Filename.extension
```

I am not getting full path, but it is showing full path in File Upload box please help how to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a browser security restriction, in modern browsers you cannot get the full client file-system path of the selected file, nor set a path programmatically...

Comment: A: the browser knows, and he passes the file itself without letting you know the real path

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for security reason, javascript doesn't allow this to happen. And if you come to think of it, Server side pages cannot access your local files. Not that I have a solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is some kind of solution.
Albeit, it will help only if you can run Electron desktop app on local machine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59990858/9390914