# Get absolute file path in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to let the user browse a absolute file path and set that path into a text-box.

Please note: I know you don´t need the path to upload the file and I will not actually upload the file. This is for internal use in an intranet where the user needs to enter a path to a file.

What I need is a button that opens a browser and a text box that shows the result. Sound easy but the input file control only gives the name of the file and I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Browse which path? On the server or on the client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get full path from fileupload using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635329/how-to-get-full-path-from-fileupload-using-javascript)

Comment: Yes, it is almost a duplicate. But in this case I'm not interesed in the file. So a solution without file-input will do. I am only interested in getting a path string by using a browser so the user don't have to type or copy into a text box.

Answer (score 0):

This is, alas, not possible for security reasons. Javascript has very limited access to the filesystem.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535128.aspx for IE specific workaround, and http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/ for info about what is coming in html5 wrt. file uploads.