# How to browse and display the image in the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've a very small doubt. I've a html tag to browse the file. and as soon as I browse the file from the local server, I want to set that path to the source of image  tag. Is it possible to implement?

I've code something like this.

```
<form name="image" id="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

   <input type="file" name="img" />
   <img src=""></img>

</file>
```

So as soon as I browse and select the file from the local server,that path should be set to image tag.My intention is to browse the image and display it in that page itself.  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am running it on wamp.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have now allowed you to access the path of a file from the input[type=file] tag for a *long* time.  You can't simply do it like you're trying to.  In order to accomplish your goal of showing the file after the user selects it, you actually need to upload it to your server.  This typically requires a page-refresh, but there are plenty of javascript libraries that are available in order to make it happen without refreshing the page.  Once the file is uploaded, you can "ping back" a URL to view the image, and load that in your image tag.

The jQuery library I've been using recently to do inline file uploads is [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Comment: But I do not want to send it to the server before I manipulate it. I am trying to work on Jcrop. But in that example they are fetching the image the moment we load the page. please check the link. and thanks for the quick reply. After checking the link please reply me once again. http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop

Comment: They are also using predefined images, not images selected/uploaded by a user.  You'll have to save them on the server, load them back on the page, then invoke jcrop and do your manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the full path to the file on the client side - which is not allowed (see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635329/how-to-get-full-path-from-fileupload-using-javascript)).

Sorry mate, but without sending the file to the server you can't do anything with it other than getting the file name (not the path), the file type and the file size.

Comment: My intention was to browse and set the url to image tag as I need to implement it for JCrop image Library. In their example they have taken the path directly and the moment they load the page , image gets loaded. Any solution? Please see the link and source code of the web page. You will immediately get my question. Please help me out. Thanks in advance. This is the link    deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop

Comment: What I see there is a simple crop function: an image - on the server - that is displayed, some hidden inputs that contain the coordinates to crop, and a php script that crops the image on submission.

If you want use a file from the client, you first have to upload it to the server, otherwise you can't do anything with it - it's a security feature.

Comment: oh ok... So as you are suggesting to upload it on the server and then crop it, in case users upload it on the server and does not crop it then we will have unnecessarily one extra file on the sever. What can be the solution?