# How to get the full path using file field in ruby on click of browse button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I want to get the full path with the file but do not want to upload the file in the application.

Comment: for security reason you can't get the full path of the the file

Comment: Honestly, I don't really understand this quiestion

Comment: I think he means on the client side, like when user select a file send to application where is that file located on users computer... like Salil mentioned: not possible

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
link_to 'download file', 'http://someotherserverwheremyfileisstored.com/file/123.pdf'
```

???

or is that file static in `myproject/public/subfolder/myfile.pdf'

```
link_to 'download file', 'subfolder/myfile.pdf'
```

or you mean file path

```
%W(#{Rails.root}/public/subfolder/myfile.pdf)
# =# ["/home/user/myproject/public/subfolder/myfile.pdf"]
```

Comment: I only want to get the path of the file which is selected by user

Comment: so you mean  the path of a file on the user side not the application-server side. I'm not really sure but I think that's not possible (not only) with Rails (see for yourself: http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile#headers-instance_method). When you uploading file you are sending just filename, type and content, not the actual path where the file is located on client machine (security reason). You canno't do it with JavaScript either for same security reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635329/how-to-get-full-path-from-fileupload-using-javascript